# Pandas : data frame transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like below:[image: Current Pandas Dataframe]

```
print (df)
   customerid acc_type  amount premium_member
0           1  Savings     200              N
1           1  Current     300              Y
2           2  Savings     250              N
```

I want it to transform to below data frame which converts acc_type and amount into 2 and 2 columns. (Dropping original ones).

Also at max it is sure that any customer cannot have more than two rows in original dataframe where account type is savings/current(not any other value).

Premium_member attribute is computed by taking Logical OR of boolean (Y and N) values.

[image: Transformed data frame]

Comment: Please add your sample data as copyable text, not as an image. Then, people can copy, try a few things out and post the answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter only 2 rows per customerid
df = df[df.groupby('customerid')['acc_type'].transform('size') < 3]
#new column
df['is'] = 1
#reshape and replace missing values to 0
df1 = df.set_index(['customerid','acc_type']).unstack(fill_value=0)
#check if Y in premium_member
s = df1.pop('premium_member').eq('Y').any(axis=1)
#change order of columns
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
#flatten MultiIndex
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(''.join)
#new column
df1['premium_member'] = np.where(s, 'Y','N')
#convert index to column
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
   customerid  isSavings  isCurrent  amountSavings  amountCurrent  \
0           1          1          1            200            300   
1           2          1          0            250              0   

  premium_member  
0              Y  
1              N
```